# How can I get import an .FBX point cache animation to Blender?

Tags: .fbx, cache

I'm trying to export an .fbx from Cinema 4D of a skinned object that I baked to a point cache and import it to Blender 2.81.

The point cache is working with Maya, but not with Blender.

Here is a video of what I'm experiencing:
[image: Blender and FBX]

Can anyone help me get this point cache working with Blender & .fbx? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Blender's FBX toolset doesn't support point cache data.  So you'll have to separate out the mesh from the point cache.  Just export the object as an FBX, then save out your point cache in either the LightWave .mdd or the 3DS Max .pc2 format.  You can then apply the point cache back to the object in Blender by using the Mesh Cache modifier.

However, if you simply want to transfer the model and animation, you can try using Alembic, which from what I saw in your video, C4D can export and Blender can import.

Cheers!